# Need some help building the ROUTE TABLE

Tags: azure, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, vpn, openvpn

I was trying to build OpenVPN with Microsoft Azure but having problems now...

After adding inbound rules I am able to connect to the server now but something get weird here since I am not able to visit any websites e.g. google.com, amazon.com, etc. Then I searched online and eventually found out that I did not have my route table configured yet. I have tried to configure it myself but failed after many attempts, need some help here.

I would appreciate it a lot if someone can help my resolve the problem since it is driving me crazy.

Great thanks!

Using Ubuntu 16.04
OpenVPN 2.3.7

I only added one route to the route table - Name: GatewaySubnet; Address Prefix:10.0.3.0/27; Next Hop:Virtual network gateway

and a subnet: NAME: default; Address range:10.0.0.0/24...

Do not have access to the internet after connecting to OpenVPN server build with Microsoft Azure

Comment: Is the VPN Client is a Azure VM or your Laptop or On-Premises machine? Post connecting to Azure VM, are you not able to connect to Internet on the VM which you SSH'd in ?

Comment: VPN client is a windows 10 machine, my laptop... and for sure ethernet is connected to the laptop and have access to the Internet. As I was doing the same things with DigitalOcean VM it was all fine...

Comment: Can you share the output of 

$ sudo route -n

before connecting and post connecting to VPN?

Comment: Thanks for your help, sincerely. The same as I have posted in MSDN, I've checked the output of that code:

Destination: [my private ip address]

gateway: 10.0.0.1

Genmask: 255.255.255.255

Flags: UGH

Metric&Ref&Use: 0

Iface: eth0

Comment: I need the output of your route table info in 2 scenario. When you connect to VPN and when you don't connect t o VPN. So that I can compare and help.

Comment: I am not sure if there are any misunderstandings... My language is not quite accurate, I sincerely apologise for that. I think my question is not with the Ubuntu server but the Azure Portal... But I am not sure how to get the output of $ sudo route -n in Azure. I've tested again and the values are not changing, they all remain the same.